# List Creation in Python from combinations

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a list each time 3 numbers are generated from a list. Is there a way to ZIP them together? I don't want to use any imported modules as this is coding practise

```
array = [12, 3, 1, 2, -6, 5, -8, 6]

for i in range(len(array)):
   for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
     for k in range(j + 1, len(array)):
         print(list(array[i], array[j], array[k]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by

> ZIP them together

but presuming you want to create a new list out of the the three elements, you can create a new list using brackets:

```
combination = [array[i], array[j], array[k]]
```

---

Also, while I understand this is an exercise, [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) performs this exact task.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [12, 3, 1, 2, -6, 5, -8, 6]
zippedlist = []
for i in range(len(array)):
   for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
     for k in range(j + 1, len(array)):
         zippedlist.append([array[i], array[j], array[k]])
print(zippedarray)
```

I think your question is solved.